# Is it true that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(\mathbb{R})$ is infinite then $f$ is open?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map. Is it true that if $f(\mathbb{R})$ is infinite then $f$ is open? I'm worried of this question because I need to prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $f(\mathbb{R})$ is locally compact. In constructing a neighborhood of a point in $f(\mathbb{R})$ whose closure is compact it is apparently the case that the openness of $f$ is indispensable. I know this is wishful thinking given that I know the result holds if $f$ is open. But is there a way to do it when $f$ is not open?

Comment: You can prove that if $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, then $f(K)$ is compact. This is always true for any continuous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So generally here's the situation:

> If $X$ is connected and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continous then $f(X)$ is an interval (possibly of infinite length or of length 0, i.e. a point)

And actually *any* interval can be realized in this way (even with restriction $X=\mathbb{R}$). And intervals need not be open, thus $f$ does not have to be open.

But you don't have to assume that $f$ is open. Local compactness follows simply because intervals are locally compact.

For the proof of the statement see this:

[Proving Any connected subset of R is an Interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205039/proving-any-connected-subset-of-r-is-an-interval)

and note that the image of a connected space is connected.

Comment: Great. I think $f(\mathbb{R})$ being connected solves the problem immediately like you say.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=(1+x^2)^{-1}$. Then $f(\mathbb{R})=(0,1]$, which is not open.

Comment: same with $\sin x$ and $[-1,1]$

Comment: Following @Hagen's idea: any periodic function will serve as a counterexample

Comment: But the OP says that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is infinite.

Comment: @EmilioNovati : Indeed, I think the OP meant to find an example where $f(\mathbb{R})$ is unbounded, such as $f(x) = \max(0,x)$.

Comment: Any continuous function with unbounded range that is constant on some given interval provides a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has to be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and with $f(\mathbb{R})$ unbounded, than a simple counterexample to the question in the title is the funcion $f(x)=|x|$.

The different problem in the body of the question, about local compactness, is solved noting that the image of a compact set by a continuous functions is a compact set.

Comment: What is the compact set that you'd suggest?