# Proof verification: Any countable subset of $\Bbb R$ is disconnected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, real-numbers, connectedness

In an exercise I'm asked to prove the following:

> Prove that every countable subset of $\Bbb R$ with more than one point is disconnected.

I did My proof but there's one set on the proof that I'm not sure how to prove. This is my proof:

Let $S\subset \Bbb R$ such that $S$ is countable. This means that we can list the elements of the set $S$ as following:

$$S = \{ s_1,...,s_n\}$$

Where $n$ can be a natural number if the set is finite, or $n$ can go infinitely high if the set $S$ is countably infinite.

Now let's define the following interval:

$$I = (\inf S,\sup S)$$

Because $\text{card } I > \text{card } S$ we can assume that $S \subset I$. So there are element of $I$ that do not belong to $S$. So let $y\in I\setminus S$. This means that there exists $s_i,s_j\in S$ such that:

$$s_i < y < s_j\ \ \ (1)$$

We have that $s_i,s_j\in S$ but $y \notin S$. This means that $S$ is not an interval and therefore it's not connected.

---

First of all: Is this proof correct? I'm not quite sure how to prove statement (1). How can I prove that such $s_i,s_j \in S$ do in fact exists?

Comment: If you are considering finite sets then this is false. The set $\{0\}$ is connected.

Comment: Since $y\in I$ and $I$ is an open set, then $\inf S < y < \sup S$. So for any $\epsilon$ we may find an $s_i, s_j\in S$ such that $\inf S < s_i < \inf S + \epsilon$ and $\sup S- \epsilon < s_j < \sup S$.

Comment: The exercise said "every countable subset of $\Bbb R$ with more than one element", I forgot that part. @JohnDouma

Comment: You are doing far too much work. We know there must be a number between any two numbers of your set because we know the reals are uncountable and connected. Call it $p$. Then $(-\infty, p)$ and $(p, \infty)$ are the two open intervals you need to show the set is disconnected.

Comment: An alternative route of attack would be to use the result that [every connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205039/proving-any-connected-subset-of-r-is-an-interval) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is good, but there are a few problems. For instance, the set $S$ may not have supremum or infimum. That's not a really serious problem, since you can use $\infty$ instead of $\sup S$ and $-\infty$ instead of $\inf S$ then.

However, you can simply take $s_1,s_2\in S$ with $s_1<s_2$ and consider the interval $(s_1,s_2)$. Since its cardinal is greater than the cardinal of $S\cap(s_1,s_2)$, there is some $y\in(s_1,s_2)$ such that $y\notin S$. So, $S$ is not an interval and therefore it is not connected.

Answer (score 4):

The statement of the OP should be

If $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is coutable and has more than one point then $S$ is disconnected.

A proof along the line of the OP's reasoning is as follows:

Let $s_1,s_2\in S$ such that $s_1<s_2$. Let $r\in \mathbb(s_1,s_2)\setminus S$. Such point exists since $(s_1,s_2)$ is uncountable. Then $A=S\cap (-\infty,r)$ is nonempty open and closed subset of $S$; similarly $B\cap(r,\infty)$ is nonempty open and closed subset of $S$.
Also $S=A\cup B$.

Answer (score 2):

Pick $s_1 < s_2$ from $S$. Then $[s_1,s_2]$ contains some $t \in S^c$. Then $(-\infty,t), (t,\infty)$ are open disjoint sets that intersect $S$ and  whose union contains $S$ and so $S$ is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the connected subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ are intervals and non-singelton intervals are uncountable.